# Dense plasma focus at ambient air pressure

Tags: electric-fields, electricity, plasma-physics, ionization-energy, ions

About a year ago I read a paper stating that a Dense Plasma Focus (DPF) could operate at ambient air pressure. But I can't find the paper anymore and what I've found in online journals seems conflicting and sparse.

Can someone in plasma Physics explain:

Is this possible?

What are the obstacles to this?

Why are plasma focuses usually operated at low pressure (of course, gases are easier to ionize at low pressure, but shouldn't sufficient energy overcome this?)?

To be clear, what I'm wondering about is, 1., the creation of a plasmoid, 2., particle and electron beams, that is, in other words, two of the defining characteristics of such devices.

Likewise, any links to published material addressing the subject would be helpful.

See diagram of DPF (which is a particular and distinct type of Z-pinch device,distinct from other pinches):

[image]

Comment: Can one operate plasma devices at high pressure? Yes, absolutely. All we need is the necessary energy to ionize the required volume of gas. That isn't hard... it's expensive, though. The problem with fusion devices is not achieving fusion, if that is what you are thinking about... a thermonuclear weapon can do it "easily". The hard part is to do it at low cost, which nobody has done, yet.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thanks for the great answer. I know fusion is "easy," e.g. fusors, but getting excess energy is hard. My question really related more to other properties of the DPF. My question was more so related to the idea of operating a DPF in air at 14.7 PSI, for other applications than fusion.

In any case, how much voltage/power are we talking about at ambient pressure?

Do you have any links to published research?

Thanks.

Comment: The experiments mentioned on Wikipedia talk about pinches, which are usually machines that store hundreds of kJ (at the low end) and many MJ at the upper end. Sandia's Z machine can create 80Mbar in a 1.5mm size plasma, it seems, so ambient pressure is absolutely nothing for such a device. Having said that... from a technical perspective that is a technology looking for an application. Outside of the generation of x-ray and neutron pulses for physics purposes I don't see these devices amount to much.

Comment: @FlatterMann Thank you once again! Do you have any idea what class of pinch machine the Z machine is?

What I was wondering about was this type, specifically (in other words, one where the pinch is accomplished just with the plasma's own magnetic field and instabilities due to the geometry of the device, as opposed to applied fields....):

https://plasma-dynamics.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Numerical-Simulation-of-Dense-Plasma-Focus-Devices.jpg

Comment: The Z machine: https://www.sandia.gov/z-machine/#:~:text=Sandia's%20Z%20machine%20is%20the,in%20high%20energy%20density%20physics.